# How can I know why an OSM way cannot be used for routing, and how can I fix it

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, osm2po

**Background**

I use [osm2po](http://osm2po.de/) in an application that needs to calculate distances, times and path between locations.

In short, I take data from [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) as input to [osm2po](http://osm2po.de/) to output a directed graph with [OSM Nodes](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node#Nodes_on_Ways) as the graph nodes, and [OSM Ways](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way#Street_as_a_vector) as the graph edges.

Later, to calculate distance, time, and path between two locations, I use this graph to locale the nearest nodes, then use one of the osm2po router to build a route between those two nodes.

This is working fine most of the time.

And when a routing can not be done, it is usually because the data from OSM (particularly OSM ways) contains error or is absent.

**More to the point**

Through debugging a particular case, I located two nodes that cannot be routed from one to the other.

[This one](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/529514936) and [this one](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/529487577).

As you can see, the only way those two nodes can ever be routed together (using a car) is somehow exiting their local streets and going through [this way](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/242078304).

After more debugging, I see that osm2po never use [this way](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/242078304), I guess it does not see it as a valid segment.

**My questions**

1. Looking at the OSM data, how can I know (understand) why [this way](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/242078304) is not valid for routing ?
2. Related to my first question: how can I fix (submit modifications to) OSM to allow routing using [this way](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/242078304) ?

*EDIT*:

I forgot to say that if I try to route from [one node](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/529487581) to an [other node](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/257868727) that are part of [this same way](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/242078304), the routing is obviously working fine.

Comment: The Openstreetmap has a router of its own. You can access it by the traffic sign icon next to the search box. It routes fine on your example, so there is nothing wrong to the data, and no need for your question 2. The routing might fail due to `access=designated`, but that should be fixed on your router's side.

Comment: @AndreJ , yes you are right. Indeed, I should have try to do the route in OSM before assuming that its data were involved in my problem. This would have lead my sooner to look at my router settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the default.config is very strict and to be honest it's too strict for my taste. I stumbled across a similar question weeks ago and modified the osm2po release notes for 5.1.0 to report this issue.

Your solution above is correct. But I think there are not so many more positive tags, It would be shorter to modify the deny-option instead to sth. like this:

```
wtr.deny.motor[_vehicle|car].no = car
```

Comment: always there to answer questions about your software, thank you :)  If I understand correctly, setting `no` as value for `wtr.deny.motor[_vehicle|car]` will basically render the `wtr.allow.motor[car|_vehicle].[yes|destination]` kind of useless, since now every values except `no` will be accepted ? If yes, I should think about it a little more, because I am not sure I want to allow `agricultural` and `forestry` for example.

Comment: Also, about that. Do osm2po persists this tag into the final graph ? For example, instead of having to build two graphs (one allowing local access (`permissive`|`destination`), and one no) , I could build only one graph with all the allowed tags, and choose at runtime which one of the allowed tags to use for this specific routing session.

Comment: I just saw the release notes you are talking about, I guess I should have RTFM, it would have prevented me a headache  ;)

Comment: Since I cannot accept my own answer, and yours is more generic anyway and most likely to help others, I accept yours.

Comment: Not really useless. Imagine a track or path where the car-flag is usually not set. Or think of ferries or railways. Here it does make sense to raise them to some kind of "drivable" way.

Comment: And yes, the flags are transported thru the conversion chain and actually exists in the graph file. But you'll need Java to intercept the default behavior in order to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I am sorry about me answering my own question. I guess I had to ask the question to think about it more and be able resolve the problem.

It turns out the problem was not in the OSM data but with the osm2po default config file I use to generate the graph.

**The problem**

Somewhere (line 188, if you are using osm2po 5.1.8) in the default config file, there is this line

`wtr.allow.motor[car|_vehicle].[yes|destination] = car`

This line is used to include in the final graph (for `car` routing) the ways that have the tag `motorcar` or `motor_vehicle` associated with the value `yes` or `destination`.

And a couple lines under:

`wtr.deny.motor[_vehicle|car] = car`

This line is used to **not** include in the final graph all the ways that have any other values (so other than `yes` or `destination`) for the above tags (`motorcar` or `motor_vehicle`).

And when we look at [this way](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/242078304), we can see that it indeed have the `motor_vehicle` tag, but its value is `designated`.

So osm2po dutifully rejected the way from the final graph therefore kind of answering my first question.

**The solution**

I just needed to copy the defualt `osm2po.config` file in my project, replace this line

`wtr.allow.motor[car|_vehicle].[yes|destination] = car`

with this line

`wtr.allow.motor[car|_vehicle].[yes|destination|designated] = car`

then re-generate my graph and run my test case to see that it worked.

Now the final graph contains the way I was looking for and osm2po is now able to use it for routing.

**Note**

Depending on your routing needs, it may be worth looking at [this page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:Key:motor_vehicle) (in German, the [English version](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:motor_vehicle) is not very useful).

It explains somes of the values we can expect in this `motor_vehicle` tag.

For example, in found that I also need `permissive`. So in my `osm2po.config` file, I now have this line:

`wtr.allow.motor[car|_vehicle].[yes|destination|designated|permissive] = car`